# Can a Mac be programmed to simulate pressing a key at a certain rate via software?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, keyboard

Is there a way or a 3rd party application which would let me specify, for example, that I want it to send a keyboard event (so that it has the same effect as physically hitting the key on the keyboard) every 5 seconds?

So, for example, I could tell it to hit <kbd>K</kbd> every 5 seconds, 15 times in total?

Basically, I'm looking for something like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) but for OS X.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a way to do this in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Simulates hitting a key on OS X
# http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/63899/72339

echo "tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"$1\"" | osascript
```

Save as `hitkey`, `chmod +x hitkey`, `hitkey k` to hit <kbd>K</kbd>.

From there it's simple to use Automator to loop over the script several times or make an iCal alarm to initiate the script at a specific time.

[image: Automator document types]

Comment: Doesn't that miss the whole "repeat every 5 seconds for a total of 15 times" part?

Comment: I didn't know about the `echo "script" | osascript` syntax - I've always used `osascript -e "script"`. So you get +1 for that.

Comment: @DanielLawson: yes, but having the shell script it's simple to loop it however you want.

Comment: I've never used Automator. Would you mind sharing a step-by-step guide? I'd like to repeatedly press Return in a web form.

Answer (score 11):

Here's an AppleScript to do what you want:

```
set i to 0
repeat while i < 15
    set i to i + 1
    delay 5
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "k"
end repeat
```

You can inline it in a shell script like this:

```
echo "set i to 0
repeat while i < 15
set i to i + 1
delay 5
tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"k\"
end repeat" | osascript
```

(Thanks to @houbysoft for the `echo "script" | osacript` syntax!)

Comment: I've never used Automator. Would you mind sharing a step-by-step guide? I'd like to repeatedly press Return in a web form.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my type workflow

1. in command line, type Ctrl + x then Ctrl + e
   to enter Vim and type there.
2. type below ; you see there is no backslash.

```sh
     cat << EOF | osascript
     set repeat_number to 5
     set i to 1
     repeat while i <= repeat_number
     tell application "System Events" to keystroke "k"

     display notification "repeat keystroke " & i & "time"
     set i to i + 1
     delay 1
     end repeat
    EOF
```

3. then save vim and exit command, supposed you know how to out in vim ;)

   - Esc :wq
4. Back to terminal to run typed above.

+++ Oh one more thing.

```sh
     cat | osascript
     display alert "typeing like Script Editor, no need to type backslash!"
     display notification "type ctrl + d to end typing and run it."
```

Comment: Using `cat` together with a here-doc seems to be kind of overkill (you don't need the `cat` part).

Comment: @nohillside Aaaah, echoes of the “useless use of `cat`” awards, regularly handed out on `comp.unix.shell` in the good old usenet days!